# java iText7 deferred with sign prefix producing invalid signed pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, sign

Using iText7, i'm trying to sign a PDF to get the signature of an external entity.
The process must be implemented as follows

- Consume a web service and obtain certificates,
- Get the PDF hash to sign. The hash must have a prefix before being sent to the external entity to sign.
- *I create a temporary PDF for this purpose.*
- Consume web services in the exchange of information.
- Sending a hash;
- *Get confirmation via SMS*;
- Obtaining the signed hash.
- With the signed hash I sign the final PDF.

Problem, I get an error of `the document has been altered or corrupted after applying the signature`.
The project implementation is.

```
private final String _pdfToBeSigned = "C:/tmp/ama/PDF1.pdf";
private final String _temporaryPdf = "C:/tmp/ama/PDF1_empty.pdf";
private final String _finalPdf = "C:/tmp/ama/PDF1_assinado.pdf";

private final String _signatureFieldname = "sign1";

private static X509Certificate[] _chain = null;
private static Collection<byte[]> _crlBytesList = null;
private static Collection<byte[]> _ocspBytesList = null;

public static void main(String[] a) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    //Certificates (3) of the service are obtained. 
    _chain = getCertificates();
    
    TSAClientBouncyCastle tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle("https://freetsa.org/tsr");
    CrlClientOnline crlClients = new CrlClientOnline(_chain);
    OcspClientBouncyCastle ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(null);
    
    _crlBytesList = getCrlByteList(crlClients);
    _ocspBytesList = getOcspBytesList(ocspClient);
    
    TestSign test = new TesteSign();        
    
    List<byte[]> hashs = test.getPreSignPDF(tsaClient, ocspClient);
    
    //Note: send hash to sign and wait for return of SMS with code
    //      if SMS code ok, the signed hash is obtained. 
    byte[] hashSignedForAma = getHashSignedByAma(hashs.get(0));
    
    //Finally sign the PDF 
    test.setFinalSignPDF(hashSignedForAma, hashs.get(1), tsaClient);
}

private static Collection<byte[]> getCrlByteList(CrlClientOnline crlClients){
     if(crlClients == null) return null;
     Collection<byte[]> coll = null;
     for(int i=0;i<_chain.length;i++) {
         Collection<byte[]> tmp = crlClients.getEncoded(_chain[i], null);
         if(null != tmp ) {
             coll = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
             coll.addAll(tmp);
         }
     }
     return coll;
}
      
private static Collection<byte[]> getOcspBytesList(OcspClientBouncyCastle ocspClient) {
   if(_chain.length <= 1 ||
      ocspClient == null) {
       return null;
   }
   Collection<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
   for(var i = 0; i < _chain.length - 1; i++) {
       byte[] encoded = ocspClient.getEncoded(_chain[i], _chain[i + 1], null);
       if(encoded != null) {
           list.add(encoded);
       }
   }
   return list;
```

}

Get the PDF hash to sign. The hash must have a prefix before being sent to the external entity to sign, and create a temporary PDF for this purpose.

```
public List<byte[]> getPreSignPDF(TSAClientBouncyCastle tsaClient_, OcspClientBouncyCastle ocspClient_) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    try (OutputStream ops = new FileOutputStream(_temporaryPdf);){
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(_pdfToBeSigned);
        StampingProperties prop = new StampingProperties();

        PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(reader, ops, prop);

        pdfSigner.setFieldName(_signatureFieldname);

        PdfSignatureAppearance  appearance = pdfSigner.getSignatureAppearance();

        appearance.setPageRect(new Rectangle(10,750,150,50))
                  .setPageNumber(1)
                  .setLayer2FontSize(6f)
                  .setReason("reason")
                  .setLocation("location")                    
                  .setCertificate(_chain[0]);

        Prepare4AmaSigningContainer container = new Prepare4AmaSigningContainer();
        
        //calculate estimed size
        int estimatedSize = 8192 + //initial base container size
                ( ocspClient_ != null ? 4192 : 0 ) +
                ( tsaClient_ != null  ? 4600 : 0 );
        if(_crlBytesList != null) {
            for (byte[] bs : _crlBytesList) {
                estimatedSize+= bs.length + 10;
            }
        }
        pdfSigner.signExternalContainer(container, estimatedSize); 

        byte[] HashForSigning = container.getHashToBeSignedByAma();
        byte[] NakeHash = container.getHashToBeSignedByAma();
        
        List<byte[]> array = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        array.add(HashForSigning);  //idx 0
        array.add(NakeHash);        //idx 1
        
        return array;           
    }
}

//***** CLASS ****
class Prepare4AmaSigningContainer extends ExternalBlankSignatureContainer{

    private final byte[] _sha256SigPrefix = {0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, (byte)0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20};
    private byte[] hashToBeSignedByAma;
    private byte[] nakeHash = null; 
    
    public Prepare4AmaSigningContainer(){
        super(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
    }

    public byte[] getHashToBeSignedByAma() {
        return hashToBeSignedByAma;
    }
    
    public byte[] getNakeHash() {
        return nakeHash;
    }
    
    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream data){
        try {
            // create pdf pkcs7 for signing the document
            BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, _chain, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, null, digest, false);
            
            // get hash for document bytes
            nakeHash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digest.getMessageDigest(DigestAlgorithms.SHA256));

            // get attributes
            byte[] docBytes = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(nakeHash,  PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, _crlBytesList, _crlBytesList);
            // hash it again
            try(InputStream myInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(docBytes);){ 
                byte[] docBytesHash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(myInputStream, digest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));

                //prepend sha256 prefix to hash for send signed
                hashToBeSignedByAma = new byte[_sha256SigPrefix.length + docBytesHash.length];
                System.arraycopy(_sha256SigPrefix, 0, hashToBeSignedByAma, 0, _sha256SigPrefix.length );
                System.arraycopy(docBytesHash, 0, hashToBeSignedByAma, _sha256SigPrefix.length, docBytesHash.length );
    
                return new byte[0]; // empty array
            } 
        }catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

With the signed hash I sign the temporary PDF

```
public void setFinalSignPDF(byte[] HashSignedForAma_, byte[] nakedHashFromIntermediaryPdf_, TSAClientBouncyCastle tsaClient_) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException{     

    try (OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(_finalPdf);) {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(_temporaryPdf);
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);

        InjectAmaSignatureContainer finalContainer = new InjectAmaSignatureContainer(
                                                                HashSignedForAma_,
                                                                nakedHashFromIntermediaryPdf_,
                                                                tsaClient_);
        PdfSigner.signDeferred(document, _signatureFieldname, writer, finalContainer);
    }
}

//***** CLASS ****
class InjectAmaSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {

    private byte[] documentHash;
    private byte[] signature;
    private TSAClientBouncyCastle tsaClient;
    private byte[] dados = null;

    public InjectAmaSignatureContainer(byte[] signature_, byte[] documentHash_, TSAClientBouncyCastle tsaClient_) {
        signature = signature_;
        documentHash = documentHash_;
        tsaClient = tsaClient_;
    }
    
    public byte[] getDados() {
        return dados;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream is) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        
        PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, 
                                    _chain, 
                                    DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, 
                                    null, 
                                    digest, 
                                    false);

        sgn.setExternalDigest(signature, null, "RSA");

        byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(documentHash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, tsaClient, _ocspBytesList, _crlBytesList);

        return encodedSig;
    }

    @Override
    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
    }
}
```

thanks

EDIT:
bug fix in method: **Prepare4AmaSigningContainer**

```
byte[] docBytes = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(nakeHash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, _ocspBytesList, _crlBytesList);
```

Comment: Please share an example pdf signed by your code for analysis.

Comment: Hi, thanks. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mmUtk6kaB36K6QZYloOdOVc41MaYVfui/view?usp=sharing) for PDF signed.

Comment: Ok, one error is in `Prepare4AmaSigningContainer` that your `sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes` call uses `_crlBytesList` for two argumwents; one of them should have been `_ocspBytesList` I assume. But I think there are other issues still.

Comment: Yes, my mistake is right.
I've fixed it, but it still has the same problem.
I've tried several approaches (some suggested by you), but they never give me a correct signature.
If there is a better approach to the problem... I will implement it,
thank you

Comment: *"If there is a better approach to the problem... I will implement it, thank you "* - Maybe. In `main` you execute the last three instructions in sequence (`test.getPreSignPDF`, `getHashSignedByAma`, `test.setFinalSignPDF`). If this is equivalent to your final design, we can easily make this a one-step signing and get rid of the deferred signing step.

Comment: Concerning your bug fix edit: now you have `_crlBytesList, _ocspBytesList` but in your `sgn.getEncodedPKCS7` call you have `_ocspBytesList, _crlBytesList`. According to the method definition (`public byte[] getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(byte[] secondDigest, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard sigtype, Collection<byte[]> ocsp, Collection<byte[]> crlBytes)`) the OCSP responses have to come first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but I can't implement sequentially. One of the steps in the process requires communication via SMS. For this reason I opted for the deferred subscription approach.
I corrected the getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes method and changed the parameters, but I still have the same error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my solution to this problem.
Thanks to `MKL` for the tips...

```
private static final String input = "c:/tmp/ama/PDF-1.pdf";
private static final String tmp = "c:/tmp/ama/tmpPDF.pdf";
private static final String output =  "c:/tmp/ama/signed.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(providerBC);

    //get (via web service) all certificate (3 at all)
    Certificate[] chain = new CallAMA().getCertificates();

    StackOverflow app = new StackOverflow();
    
    //read the HASH to be signed (via web service) and create a tmp pdf. 
    byte[] hash4Sign = app.emptySignature(input, tmp, "sig", chain);
    
    //Concatenate the sha256SigPrefix to the hash and send it to be signed (via web service)
    //wait for the code received via SMS
    //(accepts the code via the keyboard and sends it via webservice)
    //finally receive the signed hash 
    byte[] signedHash = new CallAMA().getHashSignedByAma(hash4Sign);
    
    //insert hash in tmp pdf, and create a new pdf signed
    app.createSignature(signedHash, tmp, output, "sig", chain);
}

public byte[] emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();

    appearance
            .setLayer2FontSize(6)
            .setPageRect(new Rectangle(36, 748, 250, 50))
            .setPageNumber(1)
            .setCertificate(chain[0])
            .setSignatureCreator("ORIGEM");
    signer.setFieldName(fieldname);
        
    /* ExternalBlankSignatureContainer constructor will create the PdfDictionary for the signature
     * information and will insert the /Filter and /SubFilter values into this dictionary.
     * It will leave just a blank placeholder for the signature that is to be inserted later.
     */
    MyExternalBlankSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalBlankSignatureContainer(chain, PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);

   
    // Sign the document using an external container.
    // 8192 is the size of the empty signature placeholder.
    signer.signExternalContainer(external, 8192);
    byte[] hash4Sign = external.getHash4Sign();
    return hash4Sign;
}

public void createSignature(byte[] hashSigned, String src, String dest, String fieldName, Certificate[] chain)
        throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    try(FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest)) {
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, os, new StampingProperties());

        IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(hashSigned, chain, PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);

        // Signs a PDF where space was already reserved. The field must cover the whole document.
        signer.signDeferred(signer.getDocument(), fieldName, os, external);
    }
}

class MyExternalSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {

    /* Signature dictionary. Filter and SubFilter.  */
    private PdfDictionary sigDic;
    private byte[] signedHash =null;
    private Certificate[] chain = null;

    public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] _signedHash, Certificate[] _chain, PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
        sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
        sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
        sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
        signedHash = _signedHash;
        chain = _chain;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        try {
            String hashAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;//"SHA-256";
            BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            MessageDigest md = digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm);

            byte[]   hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, md);
            PdfPKCS7 sgn  = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, null, digest, false);

            //Collection<byte[]> ocsp = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(null);
            OcspClientBouncyCastle ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(null);
            Collection<byte[]> ocsp = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
            for(var i = 0; i < chain.length - 1; i++) {
                byte[] encoded = ocspClient.getEncoded((X509Certificate)chain[i], (X509Certificate)chain[i + 1], null);
                if(encoded != null) ocsp.add(encoded);
            }

            sgn.setExternalDigest(signedHash, null, "RSA");

            ITSAClient tsaClient = null;//new GSTSAClient(access);
            return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES, tsaClient, ocsp, null);
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException de) {
            de.printStackTrace();
            throw new GeneralSecurityException(de);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
        signDic.putAll(sigDic);
    }
}


class MyExternalBlankSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {

    /* Signature dictionary. Filter and SubFilter.  */
    private PdfDictionary sigDic;
    private byte[] hash4Sign = null;
    private Certificate[] chain = null;

    public MyExternalBlankSignatureContainer(Certificate[] _chain, PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
        sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
        sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
        sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
        chain = _chain;
    }
    
    public byte[] getHash4Sign() {
        return hash4Sign;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        try {
            String hashAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;//"SHA-256";
            BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            MessageDigest md = digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm);

            byte[]   hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, md);
            PdfPKCS7 sgn  = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, null, digest, false);

            OcspClientBouncyCastle ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(null);
            Collection<byte[]> ocsp = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
            for(var i = 0; i < chain.length - 1; i++) {
                byte[] encoded = ocspClient.getEncoded((X509Certificate)chain[i], (X509Certificate)chain[i + 1], null);
                if(encoded != null) ocsp.add(encoded);
            }

            byte[] attributeBytes = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES, ocsp, null);

             //create sha256 message digest
            hash4Sign = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlgorithm).digest(attributeBytes);

            return new byte[0];
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException de) {
            de.printStackTrace();
            throw new GeneralSecurityException(de);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
        signDic.putAll(sigDic);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts and analysis of information, I found this link [sample iText code](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/how-to-use-a-digital-signing-service-dss-such-as-globalsign-with-itext-7)

***** IMPORTANT *****
The example does not solve the problem at all since the function should "stop" in the **sign** method of the **GSSignatureContainer** class.
This approach solves the problem: `the document has been altered or corrupted after applying the signature`.

[PDF signed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mmUtk6kaB36K6QZYloOdOVc41MaYVfui/view?usp=sharing)

```
private static final String input = "c:/tmp/ama/PDF-1.pdf";
private static final String output =  "c:/tmp/ama/signed_signed.pdf";


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    PdfReader          reader             = new PdfReader(input);
    OutputStream       fos                = new FileOutputStream(output);
    StampingProperties stampingProperties = new StampingProperties();
    //For any signature in the Pdf  but the first one, you need to use appendMode
    //        stampingProperties.useAppendMode();
    PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(reader, fos, stampingProperties);

     /*you can modify the signature appearance */
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = pdfSigner.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setPageRect(new Rectangle(36, 508, 254, 200));
    appearance.setPageNumber(1);
    appearance.setLayer2FontSize(10f);
    appearance.setReason("Teste Assinatura");
    appearance.setLocation("Lisboa");

    IExternalSignatureContainer gsContainer = new GSSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
    pdfSigner.signExternalContainer(gsContainer, 8049);
}

public class GSSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {

/* Signature dictionary. Filter and SubFilter.  */
private PdfDictionary sigDic;

public GSSignatureContainer( PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
    sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
    sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
    sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
}

@Override
public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    try {
        //get all certificates (3) from client via web service
        Certificate[] chain = new CallAMA().getCertificates();

        String hashAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;//"SHA-256";
        BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        MessageDigest md = digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm);

        byte[]   hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, md);
        PdfPKCS7 sgn  = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, null, digest, false);

        Collection<byte[]> ocsp = null;

        byte[] attributeBytes = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES, ocsp, null);

         //criar sha256 message digest
        byte[] attributeBytesDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlgorithm).digest(attributeBytes);

        /****************************************************
         * CALL client (AMA) -> receive SMS and signed hash *
         ****************************************************/
        byte[] signedHash = new CallAMA().getHashSignedByAma(attributeBytesDigest);
        sgn.setExternalDigest(signedHash, null, "RSA");

        ITSAClient tsaClient = null;//new GSTSAClient(access);
        return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES, tsaClient, ocsp, null);
    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException de) {
        de.printStackTrace();
        throw new GeneralSecurityException(de);
    }
}

@Override
public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
    signDic.putAll(sigDic);
}
```

}

Comment: *"The example does not solve the problem at all"* - In that case why do you post it as answer. *"[PDF signed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oP90yjPERVKuq_OmxxAWU1gXnwgtJJst/view?usp=sharing)"* - That link requires the downloading party to have been given access by you; it is not downloadable as-is.

Comment: Hello already corrected the link (thanks).
The answer doesn't fix my problem, however it fixes the problem **the document has been altered or corrupted after applying the signature** (the answer might help someone)

Comment: In that case, what keeps you from splitting the functionality of the `GSSignatureContainer.sign` method into two modes, in the initial mode the code is executed only up to the point where you want to stop and an empty array is returned. Then you wait until you may continue, switch the mode of the container, and use it for deferred signing. In this other mode only the code _after_ the split point is to be executed.

Comment: Hello mkl, I've already tried this option (it didn't go well). I have to implement this action in servlets, which forces me to save the variables in session, which consumes a lot of memory if the pdf is too big. I'm trying to implement the feature via temporary pdf, but I have hash issues. My approach is to get the hash of the pdf, include an empty signature and save it as temporary. I signed the hash, read the temporary pdf again and with the `GSSignatureContainer.sign` method (with the signed hash) I just had to include it, but I had problems again. Any ideas or sample code? thanks.

Comment: In the code in this answer you call `new CallAMA().getHashSignedByAma` for the naked hash calculated from the to-be-signed-attributes. In the code in your question you call `getHashSignedByAma` for the naked hash calculated from the to-be-signed-attributes **prepended with `_sha256SigPrefix`**. As you say that the PDF generated by the code in this answer validates alright, it looks like `getHashSignedByAma` does require the plain, naked hash, not with some prefix. So you should try your two-phase code again with the prepending removed.

Comment: Yes that's right, before submitting to be signed the hash must contain the concatenation of `_sha256SigPrefix`. I will implement a solution as suggested, then give feedback. Thanks